# Assert child attribute is property from parent class

Tags: python

I would like for child process to have certain properties, but since you can't force child methods to inherit the property decorator, I want to at least assert that these attributes of the child are properties of the class.

Something like this:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        assert isinstance(self.foo, property)

    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 'bar'
```

But of course by the time `Parent.__init__()` is run, `self.foo` has become `'bar'` and there is an `AssertionError`. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm going for using meta classes? If so, can it be that the `Parent` class is the one that inherits the metaclass, not the `Child`?

Comment: Why not use https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty?

Comment: Ahh, perfect. Submit and answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Actually, this looks great but I can't get it to work. abc.abstractproperty is deprecated, and says to use abstractmethod with property. I can't get it to raise an error either way.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of testing whether `self.foo` is a property, I tested whether it was not a bound method:

```
from inspect import ismethod

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        assert not ismethod(self.foo, property)

    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

This will work for most cases, but will fail if the property being returned by `Child.foo` is itself a bound method. Still open to more complete answers.